# Qt connect QScrollBar with QLineEdit

Tags: qt

I would like to "activate" the scrollbar when the lineedit text is too long to display on the window. I have already done it.

I want to move the cursor with the scrollbar. I also want to modify the scroll bar slider length with the increment/decrement of the text length.

**.h**

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QLineEdit* LineEdit;
    QScrollBar* hScrollBar;

    void HDScrollBar();
```

**constructor:**

```
resize(400,100);

LineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
LineEdit->resize(400,100);
LineEdit->setFont(QFont("Times",20));

hScrollBar = new QScrollBar(Qt::Horizontal, LineEdit);
hScrollBar->resize(400,20);
hScrollBar->move(0,80);
hScrollBar->hide();

connect(LineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &MainWindow::HDScrollBar);
```

**hide/display scrollbar**

```
void MainWindow::HDScrollBar() {
    QFont myFont(QFont("Times",20));;
    QString str = LineEdit->text();
    QFontMetrics fm(myFont);
    int width = fm.horizontalAdvance(str);
    (width >= 400) ? hScrollBar->show() : hScrollBar->hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the first part, you use can scrollbar's valueChanged signal, e.g. this way:

```cpp
  connect(ui->horizontalScrollBar, &QScrollBar::valueChanged, ui->lineEdit, [&](int v) {
    auto scrollbarAt = static_cast<double>(v) / ui->horizontalScrollBar->maximum();
    auto cursorTo = std::round(ui->lineEdit->text().length() * scrollbarAt);
    ui->lineEdit->setCursorPosition(cursorTo);
  });
```

EDIT:
as for the latter part:
you can either alter the PageStep of the scrollbar, or you can set it to 1 and alter its maximum value, then also the first part should simplify:

```cpp
  ui->horizontalScrollBar->setPageStep(1);
  ui->horizontalScrollBar->setMaximum(ui->lineEdit.text().length());
  connect(ui->horizontalScrollBar, &QScrollBar::valueChanged,
          ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::setCursorPosition);
  //this can also ben done on textChanged, however for the price
  //of more frequent execution...
  connect(ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::cursorPositionChanged,
          ui->horizontalScrollBar, [&](int, int n) {
            ui->horizontalScrollBar->setMaximum(ui->lineEdit->text().length());
            //...one gets the easy way to track the cursor
            //with the slider 
            ui->horizontalScrollBar->setValue(n);
          });
```